# At what age do toddler's become picky?

Tags: toddler, food

It's interesting how we learn new things from our kids everyday. I have noticed a certain trend with my boy when it comes to fruit time.

So what I do is I take different varieties, like say Pawpaw, Watermelon,  Orange, Grapes, Ovacado and bananas and cut them into small pieces and put them in a small bowl for him to eat during fruit time(just a balanced portion). So my biggest concern has now been he eats all the other fruits apart from bananas. He picks everything and on one side pushes all the bananas aside.

I try to make him eat them but he doesn't want to eat them. So I end up eating the bananas. I thought this was a one time thing until now I realized he just doesn't love bananas.

When do babies begin being picky?

Should I over think the issue or just let him eat what he likes for now? Just want to hear what you parents would do and if you were ever faced with that situation. I was forcing him to eat them but it's not working. I know bananas to be good fruits.

He's 17months now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning: Do not force a child to eat something.** - It results in them learning to really hate that food. http://www.raisehealthyeaters.com/2012/07/what-forcing-kids-to-eat-looks-like-20-years-later/

**Your question about when:**

I have been listening to this audio book, First Bite by Bee Wilson - [https://www.amazon.com/First-Bite-How-Learn-Eat/dp/0465064981](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465064981) and the author mentions that there is a flavor window from 4-7 months where babies tend to be more adventurous in eating. And then after that they narrow a bit for the next couple of years; I believe into 3 or 4 years old but I'm not 100% on that. So that may help make sense of the timing of his preference change.

I would suggest that you just keep offering a little bite of banana over and over so he can try and re try it. Most literature states that it can take 10-15 tries of a new flavor for a child  to learn to like it.
https://www.zerotothree.org/resources/1072-how-to-handle-picky-eaters

Comment: Reason for the down vote? I even cited my sources...

Comment: Very interesting, I was just wondering how he doesn't even want to touch the banana and he knows them such that he pushes all the bananas aside. Kids are interesting to learn sometimes.